# "node bot.js" doesn't run in heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to host my discord.js bot on Heroku.
I've seen other questions like this, but none of the answers work for me (probably because my problem is different.)

The problem is that my bot should log something like this when it starts:

```
Logged in as Bot#0001!
```

and it doesn't appear when i deploy the app on Heroku. This is the build log-

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.3
       Using default npm version: 6.14.6
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       setimmediate@1.0.5 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/setimmediate
       @discordjs/collection@0.1.6 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/@discordjs/collection
       abort-controller@3.0.0 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/abort-controller
       event-target-shim@5.0.1 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/event-target-shim
       combined-stream@1.0.8 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/combined-stream
       delayed-stream@1.0.0 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/delayed-stream
       mime-db@1.44.0 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/mime-db
       mime-types@2.1.27 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/mime-types
       node-fetch@2.6.0 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/node-fetch
       prism-media@1.2.2 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/prism-media
       tweetnacl@1.0.3 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/tweetnacl
       ws@7.3.1 /tmp/build_ea5a3868_/node_modules/ws
       Installing any new modules (package.json)
       removed 12 packages in 0.298s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules (nothing to cache)
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       up to date in 0.229s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
 ~     Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
 ~     Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 22.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v9
       https://fundecrypted.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

And here is my procfile:

```
worker node bot.js
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Fundecrypted",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start" : "node bot.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/M1n3c4rt/Fundecrypted.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/M1n3c4rt/Fundecrypted/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/M1n3c4rt/Fundecrypted#readme"
}
```

My bot.js file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
client.on('message', msg => {
//code here
});
client.login('my token');
//I have omitted the rest of the code and left the important bits.
```

All of these are in a GitHub repository and linked to Heroku. When I deploy the bot the log message doesn't show up and my bot is still offline.

Comment: Maybe your client.login fails. Add catch to that promise to see if an error occurred

Comment: But where will it log the error?

Comment: In your log it says `Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring. Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.`; It also says `node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached` you are not supposed to check in `node_modules/`. Your GitHub repo is private or does not exist.; The content of your `Procfile` (or rather `procfile`) is faulty. You are missing `:`, should be `worker: node bot.js`

Comment: So I should fix the **P**rocfile and make my repo public. Is that all?

Comment: I realized i cannot make the repo public since the bot token will be compromised. Is there another way around this?

Comment: First move your bot token to another json file called config.json or auth.json or whatever you'd like. Then make a .gitignore file copy paste [this template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore). In your .gitignore file you'll want to add in auth.json or whatever file you just created. Remove the bot token from your main code logic and push changes to github. Verify that you can no longer find your bot token in your github. Finally, go make a new bot token because the old one will still be in your commit history.

Comment: Following those steps will allow you to make your repo public without compromising your bot token. From there you can get the bot token in your code by doing `const auth = require('./auth.json')` and `bot.login(auth.token)`

Comment: whoops sorry. I haven't used Heroku before. I believe it's recommended you use environmental variables for bot tokens in Heroku. Check out this [reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/96wgc9/how_to_properly_protect_the_bot_token_when)

Comment: I think you can just replace that first line of code I gave with `const auth = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN || require('./auth.json')`

Comment: Alright i used an environmental variable and i'm not getting any token compromise errors, but the bot is still offline.

Answer (score 1):

In Procfile you need to have `worker: node bot.js`

And it won't log that there, you need to open the real-time logs via the Heroku CLI

Comment: Nope the bot is still offline.

Comment: First try running the bot on your local machine and see if it works

Comment: If it works on your local machine, then you know it's an issue w/ Heroku. If it throws an error for yu, send it here along with your code and I'll see what I can do to help!

Comment: No errors, the bot just doesn't go online.
And it works fine when i run it from my PC.

Comment: Could you send your code please? It's also rather difficult to resolve this issue since there are many issues which may be causing your problem. Just to make sure, have you gone and enabled the correct "Dyno"?

    - If so, please send an SS of the config and your `Procfile`

Comment: SS of the overview tab [here.](https://imgur.com/a/jPMLLi1)
My Procfile just contains `worker:node bot.js`

Comment: disable the `web npm start` worker, and make sure that the other `worker` dyno must be  the ONLY one activated.

Comment: Still offline :-(

Comment: send another SS

Comment: [build log](https://pastebin.com/YYS16SAy),[dynos](https://imgur.com/a/iQ3ecHJ)

Comment: The build starts correctly: `-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> worker
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 22.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v16
       https://fundecrypted.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku`

Comment: So the problem should be after the build finishes or in the build itself (not giving any errors) @aDeveloper

Comment: If there is no problem stated there, then heroku successfully LAUNCHED the app without build errors. build means package stuff and runtime etc

Comment: My entire bot.js file [here](https://pastebin.com/SreDgrPZ).

Comment: Look at line 54, you forgot to close the template literals with the backticks...

Comment: That part works fine when I run it from my PC, I think pastebin just has outdated syntax highlighting.